Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=0}^ny_j\sum_{i=j}^nx_i = \sum_{j=0}^\infty y_j \sum_{i=j}^\infty x_i$ for non-negative sequences
Given non-negative sequences $\{y_j\}_j$ and $\{x_i\}_i$, with the definition $\sum_{j=0}^\infty y_j \sum_{i=j}^\infty x_i:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{j=0}^ny_j \sum_{i=j}^\infty x_i$, prove $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=0}^ny_j\sum_{i=j}^nx_i = \sum_{j=0}^\infty y_j \sum_{i=j}^\infty x_i$$
First question: Is the definition $\sum_{j=0}^\infty y_j \sum_{i=j}^\infty x_i:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{j=0}^ny_j \sum_{i=j}^\infty x_i$ correct?
Second question: Do I have to make assumptions that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i < \infty$ and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty y_j < \infty$? Can I prove it just assuming $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i < \infty$?

Does https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Monotone_Convergence_Theorem_(Measure_Theory) answer your question?

I don't think so... The non-negative property of ${y_j}j$ and ${x_i}i$ guarantees the existence of $\sum{j=0}^\infty y_j$ and $\sum{i=0}^\infty x_i$, I think that is what I can get from Monotone Convergence Theorem...

@DerekPan Nonnegativeness does not guarantee that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty y_j$ and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_j$ exist. However, if they exist, then we have absolute convergence.

right, what I meant "exist" was existence in the extended real number, so it will either converge in $\mathbb{R}$ or diverge properly to $\infty$. Sorry for not making it clear.
